# How to wrapper createStackNavigator with redux?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I think my question is clear. Before I start, I should show about the project structure I created myself.

[image: project structure]

I added the router logic to the project later and I think it will work better.

stack_main.js following;

```
import Screen from '../screens';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

export default createStackNavigator(
  {
    HomeScreen: Screen.HomeScreen,
    MyEarningsScreen: Screen.MyEarningsScreen,
    // TestScreen: Screen.TestScreen,
  },
  {
    cardStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#000000',
    },
  },
);
```

In fact, if you can change the value of "cardStyle.backgroundColor" in any way, there is no need to wrap it with redux. Since redux is state management, I can't wrap the **createStackNavigator** function in the react-navigation module or I don't know.

I need to change the "cardStyle.backgroundColor" value every time a stack is pushed. How can I do it ?

Thank you for interest.

*Why do I want this?*

I created a side menu using [react-native-drawer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-drawer) as in the image below.

[image: my drawer menu like this]

In the module I used, no matter what I gave the offset props value, there were white parts of the background color; As a result of my research as a solution to this cardStyle I saw and applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to the latest version of [`react-navigation-stack`](https://github.com/react-navigation/stack/releases/tag/v2.0.1) and then use `screenProps` customize the colors dynamically.

Comment: should I switch to version 2.x?

Comment: Thank you @satya164 for your quickly response. I solved each screen inside with `static navigationOptions`